# Sharing Git credentials with your container

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am working with `Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers`. I am able to connect to the container and work inside of it.

The problem I am facing is when I want to push to the git repository.

I am following this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container)

If I understood correctly, I can forward the ssh-keys from my local machine, or vps, to be used in the container.

But I can't make it work, I setup ssh keys in my local and in the vps where the container is running. I added to the agent, and the keys itself are working with the git remote. But inside the container I am not able to push to the repository.

Comment: If I comment "same", will that get someone to answer this?